# What is the best way to open a file with its associated application from TCL?

Tags: windows, tcl

I have a TCL/TK app on Windows. What is the best way to open a file with its associated program? For example, I am generating a PDF, and I want it to open automatically.

I have been using:

```
proc OpenDocument {filename} {
    if {[catch {
        exec rundll32.exe url.dll,FileProtocolHandler $filename &
    }]} {
        tk_messageBox -message "Error opening $filename."
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how robust it is, and I would like to have a better error message. For example, how can I even detect if any program is installed and associated with PDFs?

I know that many programs (including Foxit PDF Reader) add a registry entry under "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.extension", but Adobe Reader seems to use a different system.

Is there any one best practice? I am going to be deploying my program to a few hundred users, and I want to be fairly sure there won't be widespread issues if someone has an odd configuration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write (for Tcl 8.5)

```
exec {*}[auto_execok start] "" $filename
```

(discussion [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/765)).
That may display a cmd window though.

If you have an earlier Tcl,

```
eval exec [auto_execok start] {""} [list $filename]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where can I find documentation on the start command? Which version of Windows does it ship with? What is the blank "" argument for? How can I detect and handle errors (i.e. what if no program is installed to open the file with?)

Comment: @Imbue: It's shipped with Windows for _many_ years; a quick Google indicates that it has been there since at least NT4, possibly more (I don't remember if it was in 98 and I never used NT3.5). Your version of windows _will_ have it. http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Can you tell me why this solution is better than what I have now? How can I trap errors or tell if the user has an application associated with the file extension I'm trying to open? Also, what is the empty argument for?

Comment: You can use the "DOS" commands `assoc` and `ftype` to determine if there is an application associated with your file type. The empty argument is to specify an empty title for the start command: I've had issues in the past when I did not give an initial empty argument.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example to see what the association is on the [registry man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/registry.htm)

```
package require registry
set ext .tcl

# Read the type name
set type [registry get HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\$ext {}]
# Work out where to look for the command
set path HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\$type\\Shell\\Open\\command
# Read the command!
set command [registry get $path {}]

puts "$ext opens with $command"
```

Answer (score 0):

For the records: Using the Tcl extension [TWAPI](http://twapi.magicsplat.com/), one might also want to look at:

[`twapi::shell_execute -path $filename`](http://www.magicsplat.com/tclwinfaq.html#shellexecute)